# How to modify/assign a Matrix element value?

Tags: c++, arrays, opencv, matrix

This code gave me error. The program "stopped working". May I know what's wrong? Am i doing it right?

```
short* pixelX = grad_x.ptr<short>(0);
short* pixelY = grad_y.ptr<short>(0);
cv::Mat grad = cv::Mat::zeros(original_Mat.size(), CV_64F);

cv::Mat grad_x = cv::Mat::zeros(original_Mat.size(), CV_64F); 
cv::Mat grad_y = cv::Mat::zeros(original_Mat.size(), CV_64F);
int a=0,b=0;

for(int i = 0; i < grad_x.rows * grad_x.cols; i++) 
{
    double directionRAD = atan2(pixelY[i], pixelX[i]);
    int directionDEG = (int)(180 + directionRAD / CV_PI * 180);
    grad.at<double>(a,b)=directionDEG;// this is the one giving me error
    if(a%=319)
    {
        a=0;
        b++;
    }
    else
    a++;
}
```

Comment: grad is of which type ? ooh, is it really *empty* ? you'll have to create a valid Mat with the same size before putting values into it

Comment: there is a type for Mat?

Comment: That's not the actual code, is it?

Comment: please explain the use of 'a' and 'b'. then we'll go and see how to allocate space for Mat grad properly (that's your current prob. - it's empty)

Comment: a and b is just to assign values into a 2D matrix. About the Mat. Can i do it this way? cv::Mat grad = cv::Mat::zeros(original_Mat.size(), CV_16S);

Comment: my width is 320 and height is 480. That's why i put a%=319

Comment: Why `grad.at<double>` when its value type is apparently `short`? This should give you an invalid address depending on `a,b`.

Comment: cv::Mat grad = cv::Mat::zeros(original_Mat.size(), CV_64F); and, since it's mat.at(y,x), imho, you'll have to swap a abd b

Comment: And how come you *use* `grad_x,grad_y` before *defining* them?

Comment: @iavr, short is for grad_x and grad_y

Comment: @user3396218 You also use `CV_16S` for `grad` on line 3. I assume this stands for `short`. It's the *same* with `grad_x/y` anyway.

Comment: hi. i edited the codes and made it CV_64F. but still error =(

Comment: you should try debugging: print a statement just before accessing each element: printf("a,b= %i,%i\n", a, b); You will see where it blocks and you can deduce your error from there...

Comment: @ChrisMaes the problem is with the grad.at part. The a,b has no error. printed out 0 0 but stopped working after that

Comment: are you sure your "original_mat.size()" actually has a good value? Maybe the original_mat.size is zero; so your grad matrix is empty.

Comment: you are doing some strange things though with PixelX etc... are you sure the directionRAD and directionDEG calculation works fine? did you print out a and b before or after their calculation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can access/modify matrix elements. You can build further on this base program to fill the matrix with the values you want:

```
cv::Mat grad = cv::Mat::zeros(4, 5, CV_64F);

int a = 0, b = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < grad.rows * grad.cols; i++)
{
grad.at<double>(b, a) = i;    // this is the one giving me error
if (a == grad.cols - 1)
    {
    a = 0;
    b++;
    }
else
    a++;
}
cout << grad << endl;
```

this gives:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4;
5, 6, 7, 8, 9;
10, 11, 12, 13, 14;
15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
```